# Very slow in mongoose but it seems to perform fast in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose

The schema of my collection is as following:

```js
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Device {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;

  id: string;

  @Prop()
  deviceId: string;

  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  type: DeviceType;

  @Prop({ type: [Types.ObjectId], ref: Group.name, autopopulate: true })
  groups: Group[];

  // skip other properties
}
```

There is another group to store group's information. In other words, the single device may be existed in many groups. I want to find all devices which existed in these groups by query:

```
db.devices.find {"$and":[{"groups":{"$in":["615d64780ca1a1003ec38736","615e4e513fd5450033259086","615e4e593fd54500332590bc","615e4e683fd5450033259102","615e4e703fd545003325915a","615e4e833fd54500332591c4","61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195","64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c","64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d","64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1","64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c","64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb","64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a","64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8","64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453","64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7","64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a","64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640","64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9","64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5","64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919","64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df"]}},{"type":"LAMP"}]} { strictQuery: false }
```

In the nestjs-mongoose, it takes about 5 - 10 seconds to get the response. But in the mongo shell, I use the `explain("executionStats")` to diagnose the issue and get the result:

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: '******.devices',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: {
      '$and': [
        { type: { '$eq': 'LAMP' } },
        {
          groups: {
            '$in': [
              ObjectId("615d64780ca1a1003ec38736"),
              ObjectId("615e4e513fd5450033259086"),
              ObjectId("615e4e593fd54500332590bc"),
              ObjectId("615e4e683fd5450033259102"),
              ObjectId("615e4e703fd545003325915a"),
              ObjectId("615e4e833fd54500332591c4"),
              ObjectId("61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195"),
              ObjectId("64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c"),
              ObjectId("64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d"),
              ObjectId("64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1"),
              ObjectId("64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c"),
              ObjectId("64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb"),
              ObjectId("64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a"),
              ObjectId("64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8"),
              ObjectId("64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453"),
              ObjectId("64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7"),
              ObjectId("64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a"),
              ObjectId("64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640"),
              ObjectId("64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9"),
              ObjectId("64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5"),
              ObjectId("64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919"),
              ObjectId("64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df")
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    queryHash: '80F6C29B',
    planCacheKey: '8B7143C7',
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: {
        groups: {
          '$in': [
            ObjectId("615d64780ca1a1003ec38736"),
            ObjectId("615e4e513fd5450033259086"),
            ObjectId("615e4e593fd54500332590bc"),
            ObjectId("615e4e683fd5450033259102"),
            ObjectId("615e4e703fd545003325915a"),
            ObjectId("615e4e833fd54500332591c4"),
            ObjectId("61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195"),
            ObjectId("64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c"),
            ObjectId("64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d"),
            ObjectId("64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1"),
            ObjectId("64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c"),
            ObjectId("64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb"),
            ObjectId("64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a"),
            ObjectId("64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8"),
            ObjectId("64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453"),
            ObjectId("64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7"),
            ObjectId("64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a"),
            ObjectId("64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640"),
            ObjectId("64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9"),
            ObjectId("64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5"),
            ObjectId("64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919"),
            ObjectId("64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df")
          ]
        }
      },
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        keyPattern: { type: 1 },
        indexName: 'type_1',
        isMultiKey: false,
        multiKeyPaths: { type: [] },
        isUnique: false,
        isSparse: false,
        isPartial: false,
        indexVersion: 2,
        direction: 'forward',
        indexBounds: { type: [ '["LAMP", "LAMP"]' ] }
      }
    },
    rejectedPlans: [
      {
        stage: 'FETCH',
        filter: { type: { '$eq': 'LAMP' } },
        inputStage: {
          stage: 'IXSCAN',
          keyPattern: { groups: 1 },
          indexName: 'groups_1',
          isMultiKey: true,
          multiKeyPaths: { groups: [ 'groups' ] },
          isUnique: false,
          isSparse: false,
          isPartial: false,
          indexVersion: 2,
          direction: 'forward',
          indexBounds: {
            groups: [
              "[ObjectId('615d64780ca1a1003ec38736'), ObjectId('615d64780ca1a1003ec38736')]",
              "[ObjectId('615e4e513fd5450033259086'), ObjectId('615e4e513fd5450033259086')]",
              "[ObjectId('615e4e593fd54500332590bc'), ObjectId('615e4e593fd54500332590bc')]",
              "[ObjectId('615e4e683fd5450033259102'), ObjectId('615e4e683fd5450033259102')]",
              "[ObjectId('615e4e703fd545003325915a'), ObjectId('615e4e703fd545003325915a')]",
              "[ObjectId('615e4e833fd54500332591c4'), ObjectId('615e4e833fd54500332591c4')]",
              "[ObjectId('61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195'), ObjectId('61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c'), ObjectId('64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d'), ObjectId('64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1'), ObjectId('64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c'), ObjectId('64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb'), ObjectId('64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a'), ObjectId('64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8'), ObjectId('64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453'), ObjectId('64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7'), ObjectId('64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a'), ObjectId('64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640'), ObjectId('64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9'), ObjectId('64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5'), ObjectId('64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919'), ObjectId('64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919')]",
              "[ObjectId('64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df'), ObjectId('64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df')]"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 520,
    executionTimeMillis: 1,
    totalKeysExamined: 520,
    totalDocsExamined: 520,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: {
        groups: {
          '$in': [
            ObjectId("615d64780ca1a1003ec38736"),
            ObjectId("615e4e513fd5450033259086"),
            ObjectId("615e4e593fd54500332590bc"),
            ObjectId("615e4e683fd5450033259102"),
            ObjectId("615e4e703fd545003325915a"),
            ObjectId("615e4e833fd54500332591c4"),
            ObjectId("61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195"),
            ObjectId("64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c"),
            ObjectId("64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d"),
            ObjectId("64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1"),
            ObjectId("64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c"),
            ObjectId("64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb"),
            ObjectId("64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a"),
            ObjectId("64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8"),
            ObjectId("64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453"),
            ObjectId("64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7"),
            ObjectId("64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a"),
            ObjectId("64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640"),
            ObjectId("64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9"),
            ObjectId("64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5"),
            ObjectId("64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919"),
            ObjectId("64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df")
          ]
        }
      },
      nReturned: 520,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
      works: 521,
      advanced: 520,
      needTime: 0,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 0,
      restoreState: 0,
      isEOF: 1,
      docsExamined: 520,
      alreadyHasObj: 0,
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        nReturned: 520,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
        works: 521,
        advanced: 520,
        needTime: 0,
        needYield: 0,
        saveState: 0,
        restoreState: 0,
        isEOF: 1,
        keyPattern: { type: 1 },
        indexName: 'type_1',
        isMultiKey: false,
        multiKeyPaths: { type: [] },
        isUnique: false,
        isSparse: false,
        isPartial: false,
        indexVersion: 2,
        direction: 'forward',
        indexBounds: { type: [ '["LAMP", "LAMP"]' ] },
        keysExamined: 520,
        seeks: 1,
        dupsTested: 0,
        dupsDropped: 0
      }
    }
  },
  command: {
    find: 'devices',
    filter: {
      '$and': [
        {
          groups: {
            '$in': [
              ObjectId("615d64780ca1a1003ec38736"),
              ObjectId("615e4e513fd5450033259086"),
              ObjectId("615e4e593fd54500332590bc"),
              ObjectId("615e4e683fd5450033259102"),
              ObjectId("615e4e703fd545003325915a"),
              ObjectId("615e4e833fd54500332591c4"),
              ObjectId("61e917f9eee5c1d205a5f195"),
              ObjectId("64d5f18ed5c1e5922047da7c"),
              ObjectId("64d5f24bd5c1e5922047dc8d"),
              ObjectId("64d5f252d5c1e5922047dcf1"),
              ObjectId("64d5f25ad5c1e5922047dd5c"),
              ObjectId("64d5f27dd5c1e5922047decb"),
              ObjectId("64d5f284d5c1e5922047df5a"),
              ObjectId("64d5f28bd5c1e5922047dfe8"),
              ObjectId("64d5f705d5c1e5922048c453"),
              ObjectId("64d5f71ed5c1e5922048c4e7"),
              ObjectId("64d5f72ed5c1e5922048c58a"),
              ObjectId("64d5f74bd5c1e5922048c640"),
              ObjectId("64d5f75cd5c1e5922048c6e9"),
              ObjectId("64d5f781d5c1e5922048c7b5"),
              ObjectId("64d5f79cd5c1e5922048c919"),
              ObjectId("64d5f7a7d5c1e5922048c9df")
            ]
          }
        },
        { type: 'LAMP' }
      ]
    },
    '$db': 'cityos_beta_p1'
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: '******.mongodb.net',
    port: 27017,
    version: '6.0.8',
    gitVersion: '3d84c0dd4e5d99be0d69003652313e7eaf4cdd74'
  },
  serverParameters: {
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: 0,
    internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600
  },
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1692157148, i: 3 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("5d77c22b8f0d55f9f53792626304b0b5a6159118", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7217855934368841730")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1692157148, i: 3 })
}
```

It seems to spend only 3 ms on this query in mongo shell. What's the problem of my mongoose query?

Comment: Where's the rest of the explain output (which contains all of the important stuff)? Provide a link to a gist or pastebin if needed. Also, how are you timing from the app?

Comment: I update the whole explain as above. I just put the two date object before and after the query, and find out the diff between these date objects.